# Replace special characters in pandas dataframe from a string of special characters

Tags: python, pandas, replace, special-characters

I have created a pandas dataframe called `df` using this code:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
ds = {'col1' : ['1','3/','4'], 'col2':['A','!B','@C']}

df =pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(df)

  col1 col2
0    1    A
1   3/   !B
2    4   @C
```

The columns contain some special characters (`/` and `@`) that I need to replace with a blank space.

Now, I have a list of special characters:

listOfSpecialChars = '¬`!"£$£#/,.+*><@|"'

How can I replace any of the special characters listed in `listOfSpecialChars` with a blank space, any time I encounter them at any point in a dataframe, for any columns?
At the moment I am dealing with a 100K-record dataframe with 560 columns, so I can't write a piece of code for each variable.

Comment: do you really want to replace with a space, or to delete?

Comment: replace with a blank or delete, either way is fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import re
chars = ''.join(map(re.escape, listOfSpecialChars))

df2 = df.apply(lambda c: c.str.replace(f'[{chars}]', '', regex=True))
```

Alternatively, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df2 = df.stack().str.replace(f'[{chars}]', '', regex=True).unstack()
```

output:

```
  col1 col2
0    1    A
1    3    B
2    4    C
```

Comment: Also: `df.apply(lambda v, table=str.maketrans('', '', listOfSpecialChars): v.str.translate(table))` seems a reasonable option

Comment: thanks for the reply. The issue I have got though, is that the dataset might also contain some numeric columns, whose values get replaced with NaN.

Comment: @GiampaoloLevorato you can restore them with `df2 = df2.combine_first(df1)`, or apply the transform only on the non-numeric columns

Answer (score 0):

```
## Removes everything except letters, numbers, dash, and underscore. 
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+', '')
```